# What is an array that can be iterated circularly an infinite amount of times called?

Tags: arrays, loops, lists

I have a feeling that the answer is either a "circular linked list" or a finite state machine, but the answer is probably a circular linked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).
Such structure could be implemented using array or linked list, but you cannot call explicit array-based circular buffer as linked-list.

FSA cannot be "executed" infinitely (type 3 machine only uses fixed input and reads it ones), unless your FSA definition covers Turing Machines.